# How to divide marking portion of exam class into two or more parts with a plus sign?

Tags: exam

I have started learning document class `exam` to set exam question. I can use the following code to assign marks for a specific question.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[5] What is Dot dot? What is the significance of a dot dot? Explain with an example. Draw figure if needed.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

In our institution, we divide the total marks into portions to specify the marks of sub-questions. The image given below could make it clearer.

[image]

More specifically, I want to do something:

```
\question[1+4]
```

instead of:

```
\question[5]
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a temporary solution, but it revokes the summing up marks feature. instead of `addpoints` if I specify `noaddpoints` then it takes parameters like `1+4`. Here is the implementation after changing.

```
\documentclass[noaddpoints,12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[1+4] What is Dot dot? What is the significance of a dot dot? Explain with an example. Draw figure if needed.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

But I do not know, how to do it without revoking the summing up feature.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, people may think your problem is solved. Please edit your original post and add this to that, thank you!